# How to create an instance of jQueryPosition in Script#

Tags: jquery, script#

The **jQueryPosition** class in Script# is sealed and has got a private constructor. Its 2 properties (Left and Top) are also read-only.

What is the correct way of creating a new instance of **jQueryPosition** to be used with **Offset()** and other similar methods?

The only way I see now is to create a JSON string and then to convert it into the object, which is somewhat unsightly way of modifying a single property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either download the Script# [assembly source here](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp) and modify the `jQueryPosition` type yourself.

Or you can create a new type with casts wrapped up in some helper methods. For instance:

```cs
class jQueryPositionMutable 
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;

    public static jQueryPositionMutable FromJQueryPosition(jQueryPosition p)
    {
        return (jQueryPositionMutable)(Object)p;
    }

    public jQueryPosition ToJQueryPosition()
    {
        return (jQueryPosition)(Object)this;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's worked, thanks! Unfortunately, operator overloading is not supported by Script# at the moment (although they can be easily translated into the method calls internally by the compiler) - that would make the solution look better.